# Oracle SQL Loader - Import MS Access file

Tags: oracle, ms-access, sql-loader

the question is just for curiosity if it would be possible.

In an older application, my customers import MS Access Databases from an MDB to Oracle (nearly) 1:1 and execute a stored procedure to copy the data ERP tables.

The only thing the Application does, it creates the tables with an prefix (i.e. "Elevation" becomes "Imp_Elevation"), if the columname is to long or is a reserved name (like "comment") it changes the columnname and from an sequence, it adds an ID to every table as an identifier. But that's it, just import the data and start the procedure.

So, before I reimplement the app (because it is unreadable and everything is in the Class MainWindow.xaml.cs - you know that is a bad idea), I would change the whole design.

1) Import the data in an explicit schema on an dedicated tablespace where I do not need to rename the tables. Basically the schema name whould be IMP, so changing the Stored Procedures would be a piece of cake.
2) Use SQL Loader to import the MDB, I do not want to export it to an CSV File.
3) Change the Stored Procedures to use the new schema (Replace IMP_ with IMP.)

But my problem is, how could I rename Column´s in my control file (remember the "Comment" column from earlier), can I add parameters to my control file like the sequence number and use an MDB directly.

If one of my points do not work, I reimplement the Importer like "it is", change a few things like the schema, but make I an library, not and codepiece in a WPF Window Code Dump.

Comment: sqlloader can read access databases?

Comment: That's my question Google and Oracle say I could migrate it. Yes I am think I have to export it as xml or csv, but maybe some has migrated it directly.

Comment: Oracle's SQL Developer is capable of migrating MS Access into Oracle. Have a look at this tutorial: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/hol08/sqldev_migration/msaccess/migrate_microsoft_access_otn.htm Maybe you'll find it interesting.

Comment: Thanks, problem is, it has to be completely automatic. The customers know how to use the ERP, but if I give them a new Tool I know it will fail.